# Good practices for tracking multiple REST call completions within one function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, objective-c-blocks

I am using the MKNetworkKit library to make REST calls to a server. This particular snippet sets is called when a user wants to make a photo favorite or not favorite. It is pretty straight forward objective-c block code if we are only setting favorite flag for a single photo. However I have impelmented a multiselect mechanism in the GUI so that a user can select several photos and favorite them all at once.

The function I wrote to do this works just fine, but it just doesn't feel very clean to me.

What I dislike:

- Tracking all of the callbacks with a block counter. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this.
- The same code exists in both completion blocks. However that is just how MKNetworkKit is used (one block for success, one for error). I suppose if I made this an instance method, I could handle it by calling another i-method, but that seems just as messy to do all the setup. I'd like to keep this as a handy class method utility.

Suggestions?

```
+(BOOL)updateAssets:(NSArray*)assets
         isFavorite:(BOOL)isFavorite
         completion:(MyAssetCompletion)completion // (BOOL success)
{

    assert(assets);
    if (assets == nil || assets.count == 0) return NO;

    __block BOOL bError = NO;
    __block NSInteger counter = 0;  // Use a counter to track number of completed REST calls
    for(MyAsset *asset in assets){
        MyUpdateAssetForm *form = [[MyUpdateAssetForm alloc] init];
        form.isPrivate = isFavorite ? @(1) : @(0);
        [[MyRESTEngine sharedInstance] updateAssetWithUUID:asset.UUID
                                                     withForm:form
                                              completionBlock:^{
                                                  counter++;
                                                  if(counter == assets.count){
                                                      completion(bError == NO);
                                                  }
                                              } errorBlock:^(NSError *error, NSString *additionalInfo) {
                                                  bError = bError || YES;
                                                  counter++;
                                                  if(counter == assets.count){
                                                      completion(bError == NO);
                                                  }
                                              }];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: FYI, in the future, our server will accept a list of assets so I will need to only make one call, but until then.....

Comment: I'm with you in that it looks a bit ugly, however as far as I know this is a correct way to handle multiple callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (untested):
(By the way, your current implementation is not thread safe as the counter might be incremented from more then one thread in a non-atomic manner)
@see [NSConditionLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSConditionLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (BOOL) updateAssets:(NSArray*)assets
           isFavorite:(BOOL)isFavorite
           completion:(bool_block_t)completion
{
    assert(assets && [assets count]);

    __block NSMutableArray* failed = [NSMutableArray new];
    __block NSConditionLock* lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:[assets count]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       [lock lockWhenCondition:0];
                       completion([failed count] == 0);
                   });
    NSNumber* val = (isFavorite ? @1 : @0);
    for (MyAsset* asset in assets) {
        MyUpdateAssetForm* form = [[MyUpdateAssetForm alloc] init];
        form.isPrivate = val;
        [self updateAssetWithUUID:asset.UUID
                         withForm:form
                  completionBlock:^{[lock unlockWithCondition:[lock condition] - 1];}
                       errorBlock:^(NSError *error, NSString *additionalInfo)
         {
             [lock lock];
             [failed addObject:asset];
             [lock unlockWithCondition:[lock condition] - 1];
         }];
    }
    return YES;
}
```